# related to nested view in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I have an angular app,and I wish to have a filter and the results in a separate view.Should I use a nested view,how should I proceed?
the left filter actions should remain on the page,but the right hand results should come accordingly.As of now both of my views are changing...What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to make two views:

- The former is a list view with a filters area (on the left or on the top of the list) in order to fetch records accordingly;
- The latter is a detailed view of a single record accessible by clicking the item name or icon in the list of the former view. Access by URL routing would be a plus.

Comment: you mean two views inside a view?because I have a global view containing headers and footer section.And I have heard nested views is not a good idea.

Comment: @curiousUser can you sketch your layout?

Comment: I saw your sketch. You can keep header and footer. Just embed a [ngView](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) or [uiRouter library](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to handle 'nested views'.